# Custom index views with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, activeadmin

I'm working on an application with an ActiveAdmin backend and having a hell of a time getting it to render a fairly simple custom index view.

I have a number of 'request' records, which contain an email address and a book_id, by which they need to be grouped. I got as far as:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Request do
  controller do
    def index
      @requests = Requests.group(:book_id).page
    end
  end
end
```

but this resulted in an error: ActiveSupport::OrderedHash can't be coerced into Fixnum

I can create my own custom view in app/admin/requests/index.html.erb but then I lose the standard AA layout with the admin menu et all and can't find a good way to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this using a technique described on their Google Group, in which you just shove the user over to a custom action:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/activeadmin/YgMzeYBXRno/GZ01Epyq5lcJ

Hacky, yes. I think this is a much needed feature, so hopefully someone can fork and add in support for the index view to take a block with custom content.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a better solution in the mean time. Sounds like this is the way to go for the moment. Thanks for the link!